# Use inline-block in Clusterize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use Clusterize.js for inline-block elements?

```
<div id="scrollArea" class="clusterize-scroll">
  <div id="contentArea" class="clusterize-content">
   {% for index in 0..300 %}
     <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; ">item {{ index }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
 <div>    
<div>

  var clusterize = new Clusterize({
    scrollId: 'scrollArea',
    contentId: 'contentArea'
  });

.clusterize-scroll {
 max-height: 810px
 overflow: auto
}
```

It works if `div.style="display:block"`, but I need use `div.style="display:inline-block"`.

Comment: Didn't you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author here.
Clusterize.js does not support multiple items in single row.
Elements may be **display: inline-block** but they must be **width: 100%**

Comment: @Nit Because it was not designed to work this way.
It supports TABLE so you able to add as many columns as you wish, or, alternatively you could use DIV syntax and the single rule is there should be only one DIV per "row" (by similarity with TR from table syntax). You could put whatever you want inside that div.

Comment: Someone knows a js or vuejs plugin that does support that?

Comment: @Denis Could you please take a look here to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688014/less-rows-rendering-in-ie11-clusterize-js

Answer (score 0):

Add this in styles:

```css
#contentArea.clusterize-content > div{ display:inline-block; }
```