# Less rows rendering in IE11 - Clusterize.js

Tags: javascript, html, clusterize

I am using Clusterize.js to show 400,000 rows. I tried a small sample which I found here-> https://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/NgqmVG

I see lesser rows in IE 11 whereas Google chrome shows all the 400,000 rows.

Please suggest or correct if i am doing something wrong o missing something.

My Code:

```
 <!-- -->
                    <div class="clusterize">
                        <div id="scroll-area1" class="clusterize-scroll">
                            <table>
                                <tbody id="tblDrugLUPCluster" class="clusterize-content"></tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- -->
<script>
    function LoadDrugLUP_Cluster() {
        var aRows1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 400000; i++) {
            aRows1.push('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>input</td><td>input</td><td>input</td><td>input</td></tr>');
        }
        var clusterize1 = new Clusterize({
            rows: aRows1,
            scrollId: 'scroll-area1',
            contentId: 'tblDrugLUPCluster'
        });
    }
</script>

<style>
    .clusterize table {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    .clusterize td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    #tblDrugLUPCluster.clusterize-content > div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

IE11 - stuck at 238,095
[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Clusterize.js [docs](https://clusterize.js.org/)
It's browser limitations

[image]